# listview not updating with notifydatasetchanged() call

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This is my code

```
listview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);


    ArrayList<SClass> Monday = new ArrayList<SClass>();

    SClass s1=new SClass();
    s1.sName="samp";
    s1.salary=1000;
    Monday.add(s1);
    temp=Monday;
    adapter = new CustomAdap(this, temp);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The above code works fine.But when i change my code to this

```
    listview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);


    adapter = new CustomAdap(this, temp);

    SClass s1=new SClass();
    s1.sName="samp";
    s1.salary=1000;
    Monday.add(s1);
    temp=Monday;

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Listview does not show anything.what is the problem?

Comment: This would be clearer if you supplied the source for CustomAdap and Monday, as well as where Monday is declared.

Comment: i have added code for customadap and monday is an Arraylist of SClass

Comment: @TariqIbrahim can you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148618/listview-not-refreshing-after-click-on-button

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you're changing the collection that you initialized adapter with.  I would change your code in this way:

```
// initial setup
listview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
ArrayList<SClass> Monday = new ArrayList<SClass>();
adapter = new CustomAdap(this, Monday);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

// change your model Monday here, since it is what the adapter is observing
SClass s1=new SubjectClass();
s1.sName="samp";
s1.salary=1000;
Monday.add(s1);

// notify the list that the underlying model has changed
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note that if your CustomAdap was a subclass of ArrayAdapter, you could also have done

```
// change your array adapter here
SClass s1=new SubjectClass();
s1.sName="samp";
s1.salary=1000;
adapter.add(s1);

// notify the list that the underlying model has changed
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

EDIT: I understand more what you want to do now thanks to your comment.  You'll probably want to have the adapter replace its contents with that your different ArrayLists then.  I would make your CustomAdap be a subclass of ArrayAdapter.

Then you can utilize it this way:

```
// replace the array adapters contents with the ArrayList corresponding to the day
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(MONDAY);

// notify the list that the underlying model has changed
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: My aim to use temp is because,i have different arraylists,monday tuesday etc.i'd like to copy the display different contents on different days,which is why i use one arraylist temp.and temp can be assigned the values from any of the arraylists monday,tuesday etc.

Comment: there is no method called addAll

Comment: Your CustomAdap will have to subclass ArrayAdapter, which includes `clear` and `addAll`.  Something like `public class CustomAdap extends ArrayAdapter<SClass>`.  Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html for reference.

Comment: i could use a for loop.but that adds to the length of my code .any similar method to AddAll will help :)

Comment: my custom adapter extends ArrayAdapter

Comment: there are SOOO many people saying how to do this using runnables, threads, etc.. but this is the easiest/best way.   Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much ,You save my day.

Answer (score 5):

> Why it works in first code ?

--- Because you are setting the values to `temp` List and passing it the `adapter` and it shows it into `listview`.

> Why not work in second code ?

--- Because you are setting *temp to adapter far before you set value into temp*
    second,your adapter class might not getting the updated value when you set new value to temp ..that because *temp is not public or not at class level or not static*..
Put the temp declaration at root level and try.

And please show your full code as much as required and Logcat if you getting any warnings than also.

Comment: what do you mean by root level?

Answer (score 3):

Check for a link to your referenced view in the proper xml file. Or at least check for the existence of said xml file.

Answer (score 3):

What adapter are you using? It is clearly a case where your adapter is not getting updated after u set the data in your temp variable.

Comment: so how can we get that?