# SherlockListFragment doesn't update when setListAdapter is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have the following code, for my SherlockListFragment,

```
public class RoutesListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    private ArrayList<Route> mItems;
    private static final String TAG = "ROUTES LIST";

    RoutesAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstaceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_lists, container,
                false);

            // When the setListAdapter is called here,
            // it works without any problems

        return view;
    }

    public void updateAdapter() {
        // populate the list
        mItems = Route.getRouteList();
        Log.d(TAG, "Size of mItems : " + mItems.size());
        mAdapter = new RoutesAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_routes,
                mItems);

        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked item " + position);
    }

    private class RoutesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Route> {

        private ArrayList<Route> mItems;
        private Context mContext;
        int mTextViewResource;

        public RoutesAdapter(Context context, int textViewResource,
                ArrayList<Route> items) {
            super(context, textViewResource);

            this.mItems = items;
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mTextViewResource = textViewResource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(mTextViewResource, null);
            }

            Route route = mItems.get(position);

            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.route_name)).setText(route
                    .getRouteName());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.route_number)).setText(Integer
                    .toString(route.getRouteNumber()));
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.direction)).setText(route
                    .getDirection().toString());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.start_end)).setText(route
                    .getStartingStop() + " - " + route.getEndingStop());

            return view;
        }

    }
}
```

## More Details

- I have checked to make sure that the `ArrayList<Route> mItems` is not empty.
- The `updateAdapter()` function gets called from the `onPostExecute` function of an `AsyncTask`.
- This `SherlockListFragment` is used in a `ViewPagerIndicator` tab.
- It works when the `setListAdapter() is called from the`onCreateView`` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change the array that is in the adapter then call

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

rather than creating a new adapter

Comment: Thank you! Going to try that now.

Answer (score 1):

I have to add to jiduvah 's answer.

Apparently the `ArrayAdapter` has it's own copy of the items `ArrayList<Route>`. Therefore. I have to call `mAdapter.addAll(Route.getRouteList())` before calling `mAdapter.notifyAll()`.

Now the code for `updateAdapter` function is.

```
public void updateAdapter() {
    mAdapter.addAll(Route.getRouteList());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**References**

[listview not updating with notifydatasetchanged() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747553/listview-not-updating-with-notifydatasetchanged-call)

Comment: This adds the array to the bottom of the existing array https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends T>)

It's still correct to call .notifyDataSetChanged(); when you are updating you list, weather you are adding to the existing array or replacing it

Comment: Manually adding entries to mItems didn't seem to change what was being used by the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: no it wont. As I said in my answer you need to change the array IN the adapter. You can make yourself a method in the adapter which changes the array.